# Is it possible to use Docker + apache2 to run a external php source code?

Tags: php, docker, apache2

i wonder if i could create a container with apache2 and php but have the source code of a website outside o the container. So i could edit the code on my computer and run it through the container web server.

is it possible?

Comment: Have you looked at the Docker docs or any tutorials at all?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. You just need to mount your source code into the container at a directory where your webserver will expect it. Let's say your web server is inside the container expecting the code to be at /var/www.

On your host you have your code in a directory at /home/jao/src. You could run:

```
docker run -d -v /home/jao/src:/var/www my-web-server-image
```